# Which version of EcmaScript does Parse support for cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform

I would like to use a feature of EcmaScript 6 (template strings), but that currently gives an error.

Is the EcmaScript version supported for my cloud code configurable?

Comment: What did you find in their documentation? It's useful to link to the documentation you've already checked so people know where you *didn't* find the answer.

Comment: I did not find anything in their documentation for [cloud-code](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-what-is-cloud-code-). They do mention various JS SDK versions in [Setting the SDK version](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#command-line-setting-the-sdk-version) but no details on which EcmaScript version this relates to.